# CSS - Only select the first descendant

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style all my main tags based on a certain theme.

If a section's class is red, all of of it's inner tags should use the red style regardless of if that section is inside another section which uses the yellow style.

**So my question is how do I restrict the inner tags of a section/div/nav etc, to only use the style of the first descendant it encounters.**

**Note**: I do not want to rely on the order of which I declare my tags.

```css
.red input {
  background-color: red;
}

.red article {
  background-color: red;
}

.red p {
  background-color: red;
}


/*.. other tags.. */

.yellow input {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow article {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow p {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*.. other tags.. */

.blue input {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue article {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue p {
  background-color: blue;
}


/*.. other tags.. */
```

```html
<section class="yellow">

  <section class="blue">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="This should use the blue theme" />
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="red">
    <article>
      <p>This should use the red theme</p>
      <!-- This is instead yellow, how do I fix that? -->
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="yellow">
    <nav>
      <p>This should use the yellow theme</p>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <p>This should be yellow.</p>

</section>
```

**UPDATE**

Okay so I've tried the given solutions and they work with the given example but as soon as I expand the html code to something more complex it doesn't work anymore.

The thing is that since I have to build a general theme, I cannot use css rules that depend on the order of how the html is built. A user should be able to build its website and regardless of how the html is built the correct styles should be applied.

So if the user gives a container tag (nav, section, div, aside, etc.) the class dark-theme, yellow-theme or whatever other theme, all of its children should use that style UNLESS a child container has also specified its own theme.

Is it just not possible? :(

Ex:

```
section class=yellow-theme

    p: use yellow-theme

    aside: use yellow-theme

    div class=red-theme

        ul: use red-theme *not yellow

        p: use red-theme *not yellow

        footer class=blue-theme

            a: use blue-theme *not red not yellow

            h3: use blue-theme *not red not yellow

            div class=yellow-theme

                header: use yellow-theme *not blue * not red

                form: user yellow-theme *not blue *not red

                <!--This could go on forever and in any order with any tags-->
```

css:

```
.yellow-theme anytag{
    /* Style any attributes needed: borders, colors, fonts, margins, paddings, etc. */
}
/* Do this for all the tags that needs to be styled */

.red-theme anytag{
    /* Style any attributes needed: borders, colors, fonts, margins, paddings, etc. */
}
/* Do this for all the tags that needs to be styled */

.blue-theme anytag{
    /* Style any attributes needed: borders, colors, fonts, margins, paddings, etc. */
}
/* Do this for all the tags that needs to be styled */
```

Comment: should all direct children use this style or also the children of the children?

Comment: @JoshuaK Well also the children of the children, until one of the children says "Oh as for me I would like to use the 'blue' theme instead". So basically keep using the parent's style until a child says otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Any selector-only solution requires you to make assumptions about your markup that may or may not be within your control since the specificity of two contextual selectors is always the same regardless of how close the ancestor is to each descendant that is matched, and any solution that makes use of inheriting the actual properties themselves requires you to apply them to the `.red`, `.yellow` and `.blue` sections, which may not be desired. For example, you'd have to apply `background-color` to the sections in order for `background-color: inherit` to work on the descendants, but you may not want the sections themselves to have any background color, so that won't be an option to you.

Custom properties allow descendants to inherit values from their closest ancestors without polluting other properties in this manner, and without other cascading rules getting in the way (competing rules with equally specific contextual selectors, etc). You'll only be able to do this reliably with custom properties for this reason.

```css
.red {
  --color: red;
}

.yellow {
  --color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  --color: blue;
}

input, article, p {
  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<section class="yellow">

  <section class="blue">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="This should use the blue theme" />
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="red">
    <article>
      <p>This should use the red theme</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="yellow">
    <nav>
      <p>This should use the yellow theme</p>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <p>This should be yellow.</p>

</section>
```

Comment: Nice one. I wasn't aware of this feature. But _For example, you'd have to apply background-color to the sections in order for background-color: inherit to work on the descendants, but you may not want the sections themselves to have any background color._ is not true. I posted a solution without this.

Comment: @Joshua K: That does still require you to make assumptions about your markup (e.g. 1) any element that has a color class can be matched by some selector unique to all of them such as .color 2) there exists exactly one intermediate element between the section and the input, article, p - your solution in particular is flawed because it's missing a "nav" type selector) or modify it to accommodate the selectors. Just a caveat to note.

Comment: you can rewrite these rules in a way you don't need `colors`-class. But it will get more lines of css code ;D You're right about that point, but I think that's no problem in real life. Adding a css class is mostly no problem and makes sense. Normaly it should named after the application, not the color in css, so adding a class _theme_ or something like that is possible. But again: You're right to mention that.

Comment: @Joshua K: Yeah, if - and only if - the author can work within certain restrictions and adapt their markup to suit their needs, then custom props won't be the only option.

Comment: @JoshuaK ah yes, the name of the themes are not actually named after a color it was just to simply the example :p

Comment: @BoltClock I tried it and it worked for the sample example but after I added more children it no longer worked, the styles still get overriden by the other descendants. But so far I really like the idea of custom properties so I'm guessing that with a bit more tweaking I might get it to work.

Comment: @FlyOff: Yeah, there's probably a chance it's not 100% ideal. The bigger caveat, though, is that custom properties still aren't widely supported (they are by the latest versions of all major browsers, but not much more than that).

Comment: @BoltClock ah meaning that my styles would not work on most older browsers? That's a big nono for me since it's meant to be a general theme :/ *sigh* How I wish every attributes and properties were 100% supported on every browser :(

Answer (score 1):

This porblem is a little bit difficult if you want to solve it with all elements.

You have to think the other way: NOT "a rule is valid until there is another rule" BUT "the closest rule is valid".

How to achieve this?

First set a rule for all elements that are grandchildren except the form tag (perhaps also the ol, ul, nav, ... tags) that the background-color shell **inherit**. Now all this elements inherit theire background-color from the parent element.

Second set one rule for each theme that defines the background-color of all direct children. Here you have to take a look at the problem with the form tag. the form tag has no inheritage (see above) so the children of the form will not get the rule from the closest theme parent. So you have to setup an extra rule for this case.

All in all:

```
*.color * > *:not(form):not(html):not(body) {
    background-color:inherit!important;
}
.red > *:not(form):not(.color), .red > form > *:not(.color) {background-color: red!important}
.yellow > *:not(form):not(.color), .yellow > form > *:not(.color) {background-color: yellow!important}
.blue > *:not(form):not(.color), .blue > form > *:not(.color) {background-color: blue!important}
```

(.color is a css class that all sections have, that also have the css class .red or .yellow or .blue)

**the > - signs are important**

you can mix up all the rules.

---

**EDIT** Now I see that `!important` is not neccessary :)

You can also write

```
*.color * > *:not(form):not(html):not(body) {
    background-color:inherit;
}
.blue > *:not(form):not(.color), .blue > form > *:not(.color) {background-color: blue}
.red > *:not(form):not(.color), .red > form > *:not(.color) {background-color: red}
.yellow > *:not(form):not(.color), .yellow > form > *:not(.color) {background-color: yellow}
```

**EDIT2** if you want to style a specific tag in a theme, you have to add the rules in the following way.

1) Add all css attributes that you want to style to the first rule of the set:

```
*.color * > *:not(form):not(html):not(body) {
    background-color:inherit;
    color:inherit;
}
```

2) replace the asterisk by the tag name

```
.blue > *:not(form):not(.color), .blue > form *:not(.color) {background-color: blue}
.red > *:not(form):not(.color), .red > form *:not(.color) {background-color: red}
.yellow > *:not(form):not(.color), .yellow > form *:not(.color) {background-color: yellow}
.blue > input:not(form):not(.color), .blue > form input:not(.color) { color:white; }
.red > input:not(form):not(.color), .red > form input:not(.color) { color: green; }
.yellow > input:not(form):not(.color), .yellow > form input:not(.color) { color: purple; }
```

3) have a look at the **> - signs**! I removed it at one position to make it work with all tags.

Comment: Just tried it and it actually worked, I only applied it to a slightly more complex code so I'll have to test it with my actual website but if it works that'll be amazing. Though I don't understand yet how it works ahah

Comment: @FlyOff Test it. It should work. If there is a case it's not working and I wasn't aware of, just reply to this post and I will check if it's a problem of the design or can easily fixed. //\\ If I find the time later, I will try to explain it a little bit better, ok?

Comment: I tested it and it works but only without specifying the tags, but how can I specify the tags? Like in my example I set the tags individually for each theme like: .red p{} .red article{} .red h1{} etc, since in my real theme all these tags would have different attributes (padding, margins, etc).

Comment: I add an example. Gimme one minute

Comment: @FlyOff oh. It is not working smoothly. There's a problem with grandchildren... I'm sorry. I will take a look at it later if I can solve this problem. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, me too I've been trying to solve this for the last few hours and I'm really starting to think that it's not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question, so just comment if I'm wrong.

Increase the specificity of the style so that will not be overridden that easily.

```
.red > article > p {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
.red input {
  background-color: red;
}

.red article {
  background-color: red;
}

.red > article > p {
  background-color: red;
}


/*.. other tags.. */

.yellow input {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow article {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.yellow p {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*.. other tags.. */

.blue input {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue article {
  background-color: blue;
}

.blue p {
  background-color: blue;
}


/*.. other tags.. */
```

```html
<section class="yellow">

  <section class="blue">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="This should use the blue theme" />
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="red">
    <article>
      <p>This should use the red theme</p>
      <!-- This is instead yellow, how do I fix that? -->
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="yellow">
    <nav>
      <p>This should use the yellow theme</p>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <p>This should be yellow.</p>

</section>
```

Comment: @Down-voter I appreciate it if you can explain the reason

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, but as for your solution I saw similar solutions in other questions but the problem with that is that since I'm styling almost all tags (it's basically a color theme) I can't get specific since the tags could be anything, nav, sections, aside, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To target only the direct descendant of an element, you can use the direct descendant operator: `>`:

```
.red > input {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And to go one step better, you can replace all repetitions like so, instead of having to manually declare each element:

```
.red > * {
    background-color: red;
}

.yellow > * {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.blue > * {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: @ehsan this is a very unhelpful comment. Why is it wrong?

Comment: I already tried this solution and the problem is that since it only selects the direct child, the styles would not apply to the other inner children. So if had multiple nested elements, these elements would not get styled because they are not the direct descendant. I'm not sure if I explained myself properly. I'll try to update my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
.yellow > *:not(form):not(section), .yellow form * {background-color: yellow !important}
.blue > *:not(form):not(section), .blue form * {background-color: blue !important}
.red > *:not(form):not(section), .red form * {background-color: red !important}
```

```css
.yellow > *:not(form):not(section), .yellow form * {background-color: yellow !important}
.blue > *:not(form):not(section), .blue form * {background-color: blue !important}
.red > *:not(form):not(section), .red form * {background-color: red !important}
```

```html
<section class="yellow">

  <section class="blue">
    <form>
      <input type="button" value="This should use the blue theme" />
    </form>
  </section>

  <section class="red">
    <article>
      <p>This should use the red theme</p>
      <!-- This is instead yellow, how do I fix that? -->
    </article>
  </section>

  <section class="yellow">
    <nav>
      <p>This should use the yellow theme</p>
    </nav>
  </section>

  <p>This should be yellow.</p>

</section>
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution, is there a way to use the :not in a general way since I need my themes to work with any website and since I wouldn't which specific tags would be use and in which order I wouldn't be able to specifically user :not(form or whatever) Like is there a :not(*) or :not(class) ?

Comment: @FlyOff ,Read more about `:not`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow morning but if I'm able to use it to say: Select all elements that are inside "yellow" but that DO NOT have  "whatever" theme, then that should fix my problem.

Comment: you cannot do this with this rule set if I'm right. There is one important rule missing. I posted a related solution but it's complete as far as I tested.

Comment: @FlyOff see updated,i added `.yellow > section:not([class])` to selectors, you can change this selector to `.yellow > section:not([class="yourTheme])`.

Comment: @ehsan Tried it and it worked for the sample example but once I applied it to my full website it no longer worked :( The problem is that since it relies on the order of the tags and which tags are used, it cannot be expanded to a more complex website without having to constantly go back and change the css rules to match the new order of things.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this and it works, regardless of what element is it as long as you define the parent, hope this helps

```
body > :first-child 
{
     background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but you didn't understand the question and provided no solution for the problem of cascaded theming (a theme match all descendants untill there is a new theme defined).